# How to declare and initialize a vector of semaphores in c++?

Tags: c++, concurrency, constructor, c++20

Say I have n different resources. Let's say n = 5 as an example, but n can be large and optionally an input value. I want to initialize a vector of n binary semaphores. How do I do that?

I believe the problem is because the constructor for `binary_semaphore` or `counting_semaphore` has been marked `explicit`. I've tried the vector constructor for n objects of the same value, and also `push_back` and `emplace_back`, but nothing seems to work. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semaphores (along with many other mutex-like types... including `mutex`) are non-moveable. You cannot put such a type in a `vector`. This is not about explicit constructors; it's about the lack of a copy or move constructor.

Allocating an array of these is made difficult by the lack of a default constructor. You can try to work around this by wrapping the semaphore in a type that *does* have a default constructor, for which you would use some default count.

```
struct default_binary_semaphore
{
  std::binary_semaphore sem; //Make it public for easy access to the semaphore

  constexpr default_binary_semaphore() : sem (default_value) {}
  constexpr explicit default_binary_semaphore(auto count) : sem(count) {}
};
```

Note that, while you can allocate arrays of this type, the type is still non-moveable.

Comment: Your answer isn't totally correct, I believe. `new std::binary_semaphore[integer]` would still not work because of an explicit constructor.

Although you do answer the question that the major problem here is that the type isn't movable or copyable.

One workaround I found is to use an array instead if n is known beforehand. Something like `binary_semaphore bs[2] = {binary_semaphore(1), binary_semaphore(1)};`

Comment: @tarun26: You're right that it wouldn't work. But it's not because the constructor is explicit; it's because it has no *default* constructor. There is a workaround.

Comment: @tarun26: I added a workaround to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Nicol! 
For anyone interested, I found a way to do this for arrays, atleast for the case when n is known beforehand and small: `binary_semaphore bs[2] = {binary_semaphore(1), binary_semaphore(1)};`

Comment: @tarun26 And for a larger `N` known at compile time, you can do `std::array bs = ([]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) { return std::array<std::binary_semaphore, sizeof...(I)>{{ ((void) I, std::binary_semaphore(1))... }}; })(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});`

Comment: You *can* use a non-movable type in `std::vector`.  The list of usable member functions is pretty short, but the `(size,value)` and `(begin,end)` constructors and `swap` are still available, which can easily be enough.  (Perhaps this should be a different answer?)